# If-statement with two conditions, Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm making a program and for some reason my if-statement with two conditions doesn't work. I've set it so you need to get a key before you open the door, but when I've gotten the key, it still doesn't work.

```
key = 0

while True:
    print ('Du står utenfor en dør med en postkasse.')
    svar = input ('> ')
    
    if svar.lower() == 'åpne døren':
        print (f'Døren er låst.')
        continue
        
    if svar.lower() == 'åpne postkassen':
        print (f'Du fant en nøkkel!')
        key = 1
        continue
    
    if (svar.lower() == 'åpne døren') and (key==1):
        print (f'Du låser opp døren og går inn.')
        break
        
    else:
        print (f'Kommandoen er ukjent, prøv på nytt')
        continue
```

Comment: Your first if statement will stop the third from ever being reached

Comment: Exactly. In your first if, you should add `and (key == 0)`

Comment: Are you trying to create some sort of hierarchical menu? What behavior do you want to get?

Comment: I just wanted to say I like your name lol

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess would be that it is a debugging question and you haven't done any debugging...

Comment: Writing "doesn't work" on its own with any description of what that means is almost a guaranteed way to get downvoted,  others may think that this is too simple of a question for stackoverflow but that isn't a valid reason to downvote

Answer (score 2):

Your first if statement will stop the third from ever being reached (due to it continuing to the next iteration), you should either check the third before the first or refactor the logic

```
if svar.lower() == 'åpne døren':
    if key == 1:
         print (f'Du låser opp døren og går inn.')
         break
    print (f'Døren er låst.')
    continue
    
if svar.lower() == 'åpne postkassen':
    print (f'Du fant en nøkkel!')
    key = 1
    continue

print (f'Kommandoen er ukjent, prøv på nytt')
```

Answer (score 1):

replace :

```
if svar.lower() == 'åpne døren':
    print (f'Døren er låst.')
    continue
```

by this :

```
if svar.lower() == 'åpne døren' and key==0:
    print (f'Døren er låst.')
    continue
```

the reason is when the key is one, the first if is true so it skip all other if